# Help with correctly adding an extruded cut?

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, extrude

I am trying to create this shape

[image]

but I am having some difficulty. I have tried to do it by first adding the loop cuts, then using Extrude Faces Along Normals (with Offset Even enabled), and then finally trying to delete the extra faces that are left, like this:

[image]

However, after doing this, I am left with only a large face that is selectable (I would expect that both of them would now be individually selectable). This is shown in the image on the left below. The only thing I can do from here is to start deleting many of the bottom faces and try to rebuild.

[image]

This seems like a lot of work, so did I do something wrong with the extrude tool? Any tips/guidance would be great.

(I don't want to use the boolean modifier, because I am trying to practice and learn how to use the other tools (extrude, etc), and get a feel for how to manipulate the mesh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should think the other way around and extrude the bottom out instead (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Along Normals*):

[image]

If you really want to work with inner extrusions, you should try the *Extrude Manifold* option:

[image]

I both cases you may need to correct the topology, depending on what you want to do next. To get a clean topology the best is probably to mirror and work this way:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I see. I will try to work this way in the future. Out of interest, in my OP, at the stage where I obtained only a single face (and was expecting two faces to select), is there a command which separates those two faces where they meet at the edge loop?

Comment: You can separate faces with V (split faces) but I'm not sure it will make things easier

Answer (score 5):

This is just a PS to [@moonboots' answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/269272/35559) (since, really, you want to practice extrusions, and such) .. A simpler and more freely adjustable way to make this shape may be to sweep a curve-profile down a 2D curve-path using the profile curve as the path's 'Object' bevel in its 'Geometry' panel...

[image]

Both the profile and path can be initially constructed as meshes and converted, if that's easier, and then, after the sweep, converted back to mesh for, say, per-segment adjustments, if those are needed.